# Header for website bleeds over 100% width

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my CSS for the header:

```
#header {
    font-size: 3rem;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4.5em;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 1em;
}
```

As you can see, it is set to 100% width.
On the website however, it shows up like this, with a horizontal scroll bar at the bottom:

[image: header bleeding over html tag]

For some reason, the header extends past the html tag. `overflow: hidden` does nothing. 100vw doesn't change anything either. My other divs' width is also 100%. Not getting any errors in the console. Here is my html:

```
<body onload="setBgColors()"> <!-- function that sets certain background colors using Colorthief is called on load -->
    <div id='header'>
        <div class='flag-container'><img src="images/tree.png" alt="Flag" id="flag"></div>
        <h1 id="title">Fussajle</h1>
        <button id='edit-button'>Edit</button>
    </div>
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li data-tab-target="#overview">
            <div class="tab-button" id='default-button'>
                Overview
            </div>
        </li>
        <li data-tab-target="#learn">
            <div class="tab-button">
                Learn
            </div>
        </li>
        <li data-tab-target="#more">
            <div class="tab-button">
                More
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
...
</body>
```

The rest of my CSS:

```
.flag-container {
    width: calc(2.75em + 10px);
    height: calc(2.75em + 10px);
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

#flag {
    width: 2.75em;
    height: 2.75em;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 5px solid #ffffff;
}

#title {
    margin-left: 1em;
}

#edit-button {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    width: 3em;
    height: 2em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: calc(100vw - 33em);  /* for edit button to be always on the right side of the screen relative to the vw*/
}

/* tabs */

.tabs {
    width: 100%;
    height: 3.5rem;
    display: flex;
}

.tabs li {
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    height: 100%;
}

.tabs div {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: try setting `body { width: 100%; }`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work

Comment: Did you try setting the header right margin

Comment: Can you confirm that any other element affects the size? Please check each element and use the reset CSS (you can search about it).

Comment: @Timato24 Dear Friend ! Please check my answer.Let me know if you need any other help. God Bless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the `padding-left` property on the `header`.

```
#header {
    font-size: 3rem;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4.5em;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 1em; /* Here is the issue */
    box-sizing:border-box; /* Try this solution */
}
```

You can make sure `box-sizing:border-box` is set either on header or on all the elements.

From MDN:

> The box-sizing CSS property sets how the total width and height of an element is calculated. [[See More]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

You can also set `box-sizing:border-box` on all the elements by using basic reset at the top of your CSS file:

```
*{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: I was about to edit that after removing padding-left, the issue was gone, but that I wasn't sure how to keep the padding. This works though, thank you

Comment: @Timato24 Anytime Mate. It's my pleasure. I was kind of busy with office work from some time. Am starting to help fellow developers again just from today here at Stackoverfow. Feel free to reach out to me on any issue related to front end, React etc :-)